# Is there a way to print a backspace in Python without using \b?

Tags: python, backspace

I want to make a typing effect but I can't print a backspace. I tried using `print('\b')` but it just printed out an x-ed out square. Are there any other ways to print a backspace? If it helps I'm using Mu as my code editor.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is running the script in your IDE, whose terminal (apparently) doesn't support backspacing to erase characters (it's not unusual in this; the IDLE IDE that ships with Python doesn't support backspaces in output either). Run it in a regular terminal (e.g. `cmd.exe` on Windows, `bash` or the like on a standard *NIX terminal), and printing `'\b'` works. It's all up to the terminal how it supports (or doesn't support) backspacing.

For the record, you'd want to use either:

```
 print('\b', end='')  # Optionally add flush=True to force it out immediately
```

or:

```
 sys.stdout.write('\b')
 # Optionally:
 sys.stdout.flush()  # to force it out immediately
```

to avoid the trailing newline (backspacing over a character shouldn't force you to the next line as a side-effect).